# Confound it! Why does this simple test case not work?

Tags: java

```
@Test
public void testCamelCase() {
    String orig="want_to_be_a_camel";
    String camel=orig.replaceAll("_([a-z])", "$1".toUpperCase());
    System.out.println(camel);
    assertEquals("wantToBeACamel", camel);
}
```

This fails after displaying, "wanttobeacamel".  Why no upper case characters?

```
java version "1.6.0_29"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.4-b02, mixed mode)
```

=========
Post Mortem:

Using a simple replaceAll was a dead-end.  I was just doing this for fun to teach my kid to code... but for Jayamohan, who asked, here's an alternative approach.

```
public String toCamelCase(String str) {
    if (str==null || str.length()==0) {
        return str;
    }
    char[] ar=str.toCharArray();
    int backref=0;
    ar[0]=Character.toLowerCase(ar[0]);
    for (int i=0; i<ar.length; i++) {
        if (ar[i]=='_') {
            ar[i-backref++]=Character.toUpperCase(ar[i+++1]);
        } else {
            ar[i-backref]=ar[i];
        }
    }
    return new String(ar).substring(0,ar.length-backref);
}
```

Comment: I spotted my bug... but will credit the first person who can point it out.  There's nothing wrong with the assertion... it's what I expected the output to be-- a camelCasedString.

Comment: Psst, dude tell me, and I will share the rep ;)

Comment: Thihara.  Heh, nice try.  jahroy... nope.  Not so esoteric.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is because "$1".toUpperCase() runs before replaceAll. Since "$1" literally does not have any letter to uppercase, it is the same as if it is just "$1".  Then when replaceAll runs, the pattern underscore-followed-by-lower-case-letter gets replaced by just lower-case-letter.

Comment: dnault beat you to the punch, but then deleted his answer

Comment: Yeah, I saw that-- he got me by about 30 seconds or so.  Thanks!  :-)

Comment: +1 for the solution. It will be great if you post the modified src too.